# How to lock a keyboard script if determinate condition be reached?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, shortcut

Firstly, I've got this code that load functions through the keyboard:

```
<script>
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
var keychar;
try {keychar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); e = event;}
catch (err) {keychar = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);}

if (e.altKey) {
if (keychar == 6) {$.diminuiFonte();}
if (keychar == 7) {$.aumentaFonte();}
}}
</script>
```

These functions decrease and increase the font size either through keyboard or through some buttons available in other stretch of the code. These button are configured to disappear when determined size be reached, although the code keeps working if the keyboard be used.

How can I interrupt the execution of the code when the maximum or minimum limit of font size be reached and reactivate them if the font be normal?

Since now, I thank you!

Comment: size as determined by what criteria?

Comment: It starts with 16px and the button increase or decrease 3px less or more.

Answer (score 0):

See [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

You can use the font size value as a condition like:

```
if (fontSize === min || fontSize === max) {
     e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Kamp, I've tried but until now it's not working, not yet. I have also tried with break; and return; but they block all scripts in the code. =\ I'll keep trying, man. Thanks anyway.